# Representing a non-numeric string as in integer in Julia

Tags: string, type-conversion, julia

I'm looking for a simple and invertible way to represent a Julia string by an integer (e.g. for cryptography). To be clear, I'm not considering string representations of integers like "123", but arbitrary strings like "Hello". The representation doesn't need to be human-readable, but it needs to be easily invertible back to a unique string (so not a hash). It doesn't need to be efficient; I'm just looking for something as simple as possible. (Also, it's fine if it only works on a small character set, e.g. lowercase Roman letters.)

One naive way would be to `collect` the string into a vector of chars, `parse(Int, _)` each char to an integer, and concatenate the integers. But this seems cumbersome, and I suspect that there's in built-in Julia function (or small composition of functions) that will get the job done more easily.

Comment: After concatenating those integers, how to convert it back? If you don't limit it to be a single integer, using `reinterpret` is sufficient in most cases: `string(reinterpret(Char, reinterpret(UInt8, collect("foo bar α ")))...)`. You could also use `String(UInt8["foo bar baz."...])` if your string is simple.

Comment: I did like this: `encrypt(str::String) = join(Vector{UInt8}(str), '_')` `decrypt(str::String) = String(parse.(UInt8, split(str, '_')))`, thinking that `parse(Int, "123_456")` would work since `123_456` is a valid integer literal in Julia.

Comment: Do you want the integer representation also be in a string(e.g. "abc" -> "61_62_63", which is not an integer array)?

Comment: @Hckr No, I want the integer representation to be neither a string nor an integer array, but a single integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your strings only use the numbers `0-9` and letters `a-z` and `A-Z`, then you can parse the string directly as base 62 BigInteger:

```
julia> s = randstring(123)
"RFXkzD6VpWcwvbsxOtdTxS4DGcgciKgDXECa9fEK0Djcdkcj5N75vIHEMVyuH9mcYgvFbLhbPdrKyPIO4JsK1DKgZIacov6WKDZdIpGJ5iJ15dpjmcCBCybMmxB"

julia> i = parse(BigInt, s, base=62)
12798646956721889529517502411501433963894611324020956397632780092623456213685688389093681112679380669903728068303911743800989012987014660454736389459814982802097607808640628339365945710572579898457023165244164689548286133

julia> string(i, base=62)
"RFXkzD6VpWcwvbsxOtdTxS4DGcgciKgDXECa9fEK0Djcdkcj5N75vIHEMVyuH9mcYgvFbLhbPdrKyPIO4JsK1DKgZIacov6WKDZdIpGJ5iJ15dpjmcCBCybMmxB"
```

Comment: What Julia version are you using? On my v0.6.1, your second line returns the error `ERROR: MethodError: no method matching parse(::Type{BigInt}, ::String; base=62)`.

Comment: Ah, that's the future 0.7 API.  On 0.6, the `base` is just a positional argument: it's `parse(BigInt, s, 62)` and `base(62, i)`.

Answer (score 0):

I created a (somewhat complicated) implementation that works for ASCII strings:

```
stringToInt(str::String) = sum(i -> Int(str[end-i]) * 128^i, 0:length(str)-1)

function intToString(m::Int)
  chars = Char[]
  for n in div(ceil(Int, log2(x)), 7)-1:-1:0
    d, m = divrem(m, 128^n)
    push!(chars, d)
  end
  String(chars)
end
```

Let me know if you can think of a better one.